# Linq hide records where all status in the same processid are in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code

```
var validReasons = new List<string>{"CLOSE", "OPEN", "DEL", "ARCCHIVE", "HOLD", "REP"};
        var processList = new List<ProcessItem>{
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 1, Status = "ARCCHIVE"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 1, Status = "ARCCHIVE"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 3, Status = "xx"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 3, Status = "xx"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 4, Status = "xx"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 5, Status = "xx"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 5, Status = "xx"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 6, Status = "CLOSE"},
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 6, Status = "CLOSE"}, 
            new ProcessItem{ProcessId = 6, Status = "xx"}};
        
        
        var data = processList.GroupBy(p => p.ProcessId).Where(g => g.All(item => !validReasons.Contains(item.Status))).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
        
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ProcessId: {item.ProcessId}, Status: {item.Status}");
        }
```

The current output is

```
ProcessId: 3, Status: xx
ProcessId: 3, Status: xx
ProcessId: 4, Status: xx
ProcessId: 5, Status: xx
ProcessId: 5, Status: xx
```

but what I need to show ProcessId 6 as not all the Statuses are in the validReasons list.
The expected result should be :

```
ProcessId: 3, Status: xx
ProcessId: 3, Status: xx
ProcessId: 4, Status: xx
ProcessId: 5, Status: xx
ProcessId: 5, Status: xx
ProcessId: 6, Status: CLOSE
ProcessId: 6, Status: CLOSE
ProcessId: 6, Status: xx
```

Is it possible to do it with linq?

Comment: try moving the ! from the validreasons.contains to the g.all. That way it will fail only if ALL in g have a status in valid reasons, instead of succeeding only if none do.

Comment: The alternative is to change .All() to .Any() in your original code.  `.Where(g => g.Any(item => !validReasons.Contains(item.Status)))`. Same result as Moige's answer above.

Comment: T N's solution is the correct one. You don't need to check all processes with the same id if you've already found one that's not acceptable. Using any if more optimized.